# Creating Angular-UI Bootstrap Popover that appears at start and disappears on click away

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a popover for a button or div that I want the user to click. The popover should display at the start when the screen loads and the user should be able to click on it to make it disappear (either the popover or the button).

Has anyone tried to do anything similar before?

I'd prefer to use the Angular-UI Library (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) if possible but other solutions would be great too.

I have tried using stuff similar to this but the popover clearly only appears on mouseenter or click/focus if I change the trigger. 
    Enter a post

Any help would be much appreciated!